# How to set index.html as root file in Nginx?

Tags: configuration, nginx

How to set index.html for the domain name e.g. https://www.example.com/ - leads user to index.html in root directory.

I've tried different things like:

```
server {
    # some configs

    location = / {
            index index.html;
            fastcgi_index index.html;
    }
or 
    location / {
            index index.html;
            fastcgi_index index.html;
    }

}
```

Nothing helped me.

There are some other configs with location keyword, though I'd commented them either.

Other "location" configs in the `server {` clause:

```
location ~ .*(css|htc|js|bmp|jp?g|gif|ico|cur|png|swf|htm?|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        root $www_root;
}

location ~ \.php$
{
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        index                           index.html;
        fastcgi_index                   index.html;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $www_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9000;
        # Директива определяет что ответы FastCGI-сервера с кодом больше или равные 400
        # перенаправлять на обработку nginx'у с помощью директивы error_page
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        break;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

All them were commented and uncommented, but nothing helped.

PS Editions were made in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domainname.com file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer is to place the root dir to the location directives:

```
root   /srv/www/ducklington.org/public_html;
```

Comment: for me `index.html` works perfectly. It doesn't matter at all, it's just a name of a file on the filesystem.

Comment: I have no idea what “place the root dir to the location directives” means. This answer needs to be clarified to be useful. What is that code? Where do you put it? Why?

Answer (score 67):

in your location block you can do:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
}
```

which will tell ngingx to look for a file with the exact name given first, and if none such file is found it will try uri/index.html. So if a request for https://www.example.com/ comes it it would look for an exact file match first, and not finding that would then check for index.html

Comment: Look like it results in infinite loop if the folder doesn't contains index.html

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider this to be a best practice or anything.  If you can't find the file or directory you are looking for, it really should return a 404, not the index.

Comment: it will only return the index if it's a directory-name otherwise you'd be looking for <filename>\index.html which won't be there and will thus return 404

Comment: Note that, if your location is something else than / (e.g. /blog/), the try_files would be ```$uri $uri/blog/index.html```.

Comment: You probably want to set it to `try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;` to fallback to 404 instead of 500.

Comment: I agree with @PhươngNguyễn that this results in an infinite loop

Comment: I have tested this configuration with proposed `try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;` on an empty folder and it just return 404, no infinite loops from my browser side at least.

Comment: I just add 2 cent: append `=404` at `try_files`, because if someone is looking for a non-existent file it gives you a 500 server error

Comment: Delete this answer. It is no longer valid.

Answer (score 50):

`location / {` is the most general location (with `location {`). It will match anything, [AFAIU](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms). I doubt that it would be useful to have `location / { index index.html; }` because of a lot of duplicate content for every subdirectory of your site.

The approach with

> try_files $uri $uri/index.html index.html;

is bad, as mentioned in a comment above, because it returns `index.html` for pages which should not exist on your site (any possible `$uri` will end up in that).
Also, as mentioned in an answer above, there is an internal redirect in the last argument of `try_files`.

Your approach

> ```
> location = / {
>    index index.html;
> ```

is also bad, since `index` makes an internal redirect too. In case you want that, you should be able to handle that in a specific `location`. Create e.g.

```
location = /index.html {
```

as was proposed [here](https://www.tollmanz.com/nginx-location-match-homepage/). But then you will have a working link `http://example.org/index.html`, which may be not desired. Another variant, which I use, is:

```
root /www/my-root;

# http://example.org
# = means exact location
location = / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}

# disable http://example.org/index as a duplicate content
location = /index      { return 404; }

# This is a general location. 
# (e.g. http://example.org/contacts <- contacts.html)
location / {
    # use fastcgi or whatever you need here
    # return 404 if doesn't exist
    try_files $uri.html =404;
}
```

P.S. It's extremely easy to [debug](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) nginx (if your binary allows that). Just add into the `server {` block:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
```

and see there all internal redirects etc.

Comment: If you are hosting other files than html (such as javaScript or images) I think you want the 2nd to last line to be:
`try_files $uri $uri.html =404;`

To make index.html return 404, you can then do:
`location = /index      { return 404; }`                                                                    `location = /index.html { return 404; }`

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation
Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing; the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives. It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”. If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made. Important

> an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is
>   made.

So in last parameter you should add your page or code if first two parameters returns false.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html index.html;
}
```

Comment: It's checks files after try_files - If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made. If you want to see 404 Code page in case if all files not found you need specified it as last argument.
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}

Answer (score 5):

For me, the `try_files` directive in the (currently most voted) answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957896/608359 led to rewrite cycles,

```
*173 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting
```

I had better luck with the index directive. Note that I used a forward slash before the name, which might or might not be what you want.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  root /home/dclo/example;
  index /index.html;
  error_page 404 /index.html;

  # ... ssl configuration
}
```

In this case, I wanted all paths to lead to /index.html, including when returning a 404.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the location block in nginx works for me

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
```

thats the entire block

```
location / {
  expires -1;
  add_header Pragma "no-cache";
  add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
  root /var/www
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```