# My website won't open unless I add "/index.html" to the end of it

Tags: html, server

My Website was finally live when I realized that I can't get to it unless I add "index.html"

I think I know what I did but I don't know how to fix it....

I deleted the "index.html" file from my server to start all the way over and then when I made a new "index.html" and tried it. it would displays this...

" Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. "

And when I add "/index.html" to the end of my domain.com it works.... perfectly.

Please help I would like to get this site back up in the next few days.

Comment: Are you using nginx? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954255/nginx-how-to-set-index-html-as-root-file

Comment: Check file permissions - should be `rw-r-r--`

Comment: try making the directory your files are in (the directory itself, not necessarily its contents) have the execute flag.  `sudo chmod +x /directory/name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the htaccess file and if there is not one you can create one and upload it to your server.

in the file you should have a line like this:

DirectoryIndex index.html

If not, Again create the file and add that line of code. This will direct all traffic to your index.html page when they enter your domain name or any traffic going to that domain name.

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked..                                                                                                         before the line of code was "DirectoryIndex index.php"                                  I just changed it to "DirectoryIndex index.html" and it worked:)                       I can't believed it took only one line of code. Thanks again!

Comment: @CheerfulGodwin, No problem.. its a basic but yet effective way of doing things. Sometimes the basic way is the best way :) Hope everything goes well for you in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but this is because the "default document" setting needs to be set so that navigating to a directory automatically directs to index.html.

[Here's how to do it in IIS.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the index.html isn't set as default document anymore or not on top of all default documents?

Comment: How would I set as my default document?

Comment: This has to be set in your web server. Are you using IIS as web server?

Answer (score 0):

This should be an easy fix. Do you have full admin access to the domain? The domain registrar may have your public folder under a special route. Is it possible that you uploaded the file to an incorrect folder? You should not have to add "/" to access the index file in order for it to work.

Is your website still live?