# How to returns index.html as top domain not /index.html on Nginx?

Tags: html, nginx

I tried below nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri.html $uri @proxy;
        access_log off;
    }
    ...
}
```

But I couldn't access to my site with `/`. I can access to my site with `/index` or `/index.html` though.

How can I access to mysite with `/`?

Comment: I do not know about the `@proxy` thing, but seems you are on the right path "duplicate": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954255/nginx-how-to-set-index-html-as-root-file. %)p.

Comment: I tried `try_files $url.html uri/index.html @proxy` and this worked as I expected. Nginx returns index.html as top route(`/`).