# Nginx giving 404 Not Found (ubuntu)

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to configure `nginx` to display a page (index.html) inside my folder `/var/www/Exercises/PHP/taskList` but it's only displaying `404 Not Found`. This is my configuration file inside `sites-enabled` folder:

```
server {
  listen localhost:80;

  server_name taskList.dev *.taskList.dev;

  root /var/www/Exercises/PHP/taskList;

  access_log /var/log/taskList.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/taskList.error.log warn;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000; includeSubdomains";
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

  include conf.d/server/remove-trailing-slash.conf;
  include conf.d/server/symfony2.conf;
  include conf.d/server/fastcgi.conf;
  include conf.d/server/chromeframe.conf;
  include conf.d/server/deny.conf;
}
```

And I've got this in my `host` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1 taskList.dev
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing, I did some research but I'm stuck with the 404 error page.

Comment: Any error/info from access and error file? Does /var/www/Exercises/PHP/taskList exist? Does it have index.html inside? What's permission of /var/www/Exercises/PHP/taskList/index.html?

Comment: You are missing a location block. Look at this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954255/how-to-set-index-html-as-root-file-in-nginx?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Add a location block, you'll probably want to use try_files as well, something like this:

```
location / { try_files $uri =404; }
```