# Configure nginx to use files and folders with the same name

Tags: php, nginx

I am taking over a website from a sister company and their site has several places where a folder will have a sub folder and a `.php` file with the same name. For example, the `parts` folder will have a `store` folder that contains several more files and folders but it contains a `store.php` file as well. nginx is throwing a forbidden error because it thinks the user is trying to list the folder directory but the url `/parts/store/` should show the `store.php` file and still allow the user to go to `/parts/store/category/product` and should show a product file nested in the `parts/store/` sub folders.

Comment: A good practice would be to have the files that are suposed to be folder indexes named ìndex.php` and rewrite everything that is not a file or folder to it. Is that a possibility for you?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As long as I can keep the url structure from changing, that may be a possibility. Would I be able to keep the rest of the requests where the last segment is the name of the php file and the rest is the path leading up to it?

Comment: actualy, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957896/643039) might be helpfull to you

Comment: That seems to just send everything to index

Comment: Renaming the files to index.php and placing them in their matching folders worked perfectly. If you want to make an answer, I will mark it correct if SO will allow me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to rename the files you want to be directory index as indes.php if your Nginx configuration allows for that. That in my mind is the simplest solution and is most inline with web standards.